# Drop Down Menu Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I wanted to use this menu http://www.renatoweb.it/menu15.htm
such a Drop Down "MultiLevel" Menu but I can't do it.
I added one another level.
When I click the father, the sub-menu is showed, but when I click one element of the sub-menu the menu is automatically closed.

So, I deleted line 214 *//options.active = clickedActive ? $([]) : clicked;* 
so the menu have "memory",but I can't close clicked voice after.

Now this is the problem:
How can I close the showed sub-menu at the click?

Comment: Please add your relevant code (jQuery + HTML) to the question, without it, your question is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: always provide your code in order to receive help, not mind reader please...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vE3S7/

This is my code. I don't know why the editor doesn't show the menu in a right way.
Anyway, 
I want that "AZIENDA" has a three sublevel, "ORGANIZZAZIONE", "RISORSE", "RAPPORTI". And this is works.
Now, when I click "ORGANIZZAZIONE"  that contains three elements, the entire menu is closed because "AZIENDA" (the father) is closed, but "ORGANIZZAZIONE" is open (I see this viewing the code).
When I delete the line <i>//options.active = clickedActive ? $([]) : clicked</i> I obtain what I want.

But I can't close the menu. And this is my problem.